# How to remove a single quotes from a list?

Tags: python

```
##i have the data to append to a Arraylist
Global = 'none' ##Basically i need to append this header
header = ['/', Global.strip("'"), 0] ##header
['/', 'none', 0]     ##Actual Output
['/', none, 0]      ##I need the Expected Output without single quotes
```

Comment: Sorry what are expecting `null` to be here? A string or `None` as in `None` python object

Comment: your question is unclear, please rewrite it

Comment: A string as none,I need to remove the single quotes for none

Comment: If you `print()` a sting it won't have quotes put around it.

Comment: The quotes are visually indicating that the value is a string. When you print out the array items or write to a file, the quotes aren't there.

Comment: I need the value to be stored and used,I don't want to print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works exactly how you want it :-

```
    Global = 'none' 
    header = ['/', Global, 0]
    print ('[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, header)).replace( "/","'/'"))
```

Output :- ['/', none, 0] 
(You can check it out here  https://onlinegdb.com/rJ5COTye4)

Comment: a = '[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, header)).replace( "/","'/'") ,                                      >>> a
"['/', none, 0]" ,how can i remove double quotations and store

Comment: a.replace(' " ') possibly .I would need to be near my machine to be certain. Will try it when i get in tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between what characters a string **contains** and how it **represented** (e.g. when using the python repl. See this example:

```
>>> x = "hello"
>>> x
'hello'
>>> print(x)
hello
>>>
```

The string `x` above doesn't contain any quotes, it's just displayed this way. This is used to e.g. make numbers and strings that contain numbers look different:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = "1"
>>> a
1
>>> b
'1'
```

Does this help? If not, please clarify whether you're talking about the data representation or the actual data itself.

Comment: I dont want to print the value,I want the variable to be stored and use it. Like x = hello.

Comment: What are you using the value for? What's the overall task of the program you're writing?

Comment: I writing a program for UI puprose,where i am passing the data to a Data table of javascript,if i pass the header it is coming with single quotes,so i dont need single quotes   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(

          [['Location', 'Parent', 'size'], ['/', 'none', 0],  ['warehouse-hive-events-schema', '/', 17754]
);

Comment: are you using your python program to write javascript code?

Comment: sry,not javascript,building a flask application rendering the values to a html template.  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable( [['Location', 'Parent', 'size'], ['/', 'none', 0], ['warehouse-hive-events-schema', '/', 17754] );

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
Global = 'none' 
header = ['/', Global, 0] 
print ('[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, header)))
```